# What does 片 mean in 右肩已经一片麻木?

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, sentence-structure

This is the whole paragraph:

车已经开了快三个小时了，车窗外的天还是很阴沉，身边坐的姑娘还在睡，脑门儿很踏实地枕在他肩上，**右肩已经一片麻木**。

It cannon be a measure word, since 麻木 is an adjective, right?

Also, the 一 yi means A/AN or ALL/WHOLE in this context?

Answer (score 1):

片 has a meaning of "layered", and 一片 means "one layer of", in which, the layer of the substance has the sense that it covers/spreads out a wide area over something, such as "一片汪洋" - a wide (spread) ocean, "一片黑暗" - a wide (spread) darkness, and "一片白雪覆蓋着大地" - the ground is covered by a layer of white snow.

一片麻木 means a wide (spread) numbness. In which, 麻木 is a noun.

Answer (score 1):

一片：all, completely, a scene of ....

车已经开了快三个小时了，
(I've been) driving almost three hours now,
车窗外的天还是很阴沉，
outside the car window (everything) is still dark and gloomy,
身边坐的姑娘还在睡，
the girl sitting next to me is sleeping,
脑门儿很踏实地枕在他肩上，
(her) forehead resting on the pillow at her shoulder
右肩已经一片麻木。
(her) right shoulder was already completely numb. (How do you know that if she's asleep??)

天空一片蔚蓝。
The sky was a brilliant blue.

选举之后是一片狂喜。
After the election all was euphoria.